# Drupal 7 Template Suggestions not working

Tags: drupal-7

If I create a region in the info file like:

```
regions[footer_panel] = Footer panel
```

then render this in the page template (page.tpl.php):

```
print render($page['footer_panel']);
```

then try and create an overide template to work with (as described in documentation):

**block--footer_panel.tpl.php**

finally print some static text in that file, Im not getting any results. Please could someone advise?

***Caches have been flushed and block.tpl is in the templates folder.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try adding the generic block.tpl.php to the theme as well.  Sometimes it won't pick up the block template suggestions if that file isn't present first. Be sure to clear the cache again.
2. I'm also assuming that you have a block inserted into that region.  If you do not have a block designated to show in that region creating a template file will do nothing.  You need to create a block and then create the template file based on that blocks name/ID not the region name.

Comment: "If you do not have a block designated to show in that region creating a template file will do nothing." Thanks jsheffers